# Animate View constraint while scrolling

Tags: uitableview, animation, swift3, scroll, uisearchbar

How to animate `UISearchBar` constraint based on `UITableView` scrolling?

[image]

Above image illustrates my development screen.

While scrolling `UITableView`, `UINavigationBar` will remain without changes but `UISearchBar` goes up behind `UINavigationBar` and SortView will touch `UINavigationBar`(`UISearchBar` and SortView) through animation while scrolling `UITableView`. How can I achieve this? I mean, How to update constraints while scrolling.

Note: I did some coding but by dragging `UITableView` forcibly, `UISearchBar` constraint getting corrupted.

Please improve my question if needed.

Thanks in advance.